# Integration by parts. Push It to the Limit

Tags: integration, derivatives, exponential-function, differential-operators

Given a function $f$, a primitive $F$ is given by
$$
F(x)=\int\,f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.
$$
Using repeated integration by parts it seems that one can rewrite $F$ as
$$
F(x)=xf(x)-\frac{1}{2!}x^2f'(x)+\frac{1}{3!}x^3f''(x)-\frac{1}{4!}x^4f'''(x)+\cdots+(-1)^{k+1}\frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}f^{(k)}(x)+\cdots
$$
or as
\begin{align*}
F(x)&=\Bigg[\sum_{k\geq0}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\partial_x^k\Bigg]f(x)\\
&=\frac{e^{-x\partial_x}-1}{\partial_x}f(x).
\end{align*}
Does this have some utility, application or use somewhere?

Comment: This is one of the usual ways of proving Taylor's Theorem, although you need to be more careful with signs and limits of integration. You can see it on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Derivation_for_the_integral_form_of_the_remainder

Comment: It should be pointed out that $e^{-x\partial_x}$ is *not* $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^k}{k!} \partial_x^k$ as you suggest, but $$e^{-x\partial_x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}(-x\partial_x)^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\underbrace{(-x\partial_x)\circ(-x\partial_x)\cdots\circ(-x\partial_x)}_{k\text{ times}}$$ For instance, $$(-x\partial_x)^2=-x\partial_x(-x\partial_x)=x\partial_x+x^2\partial^2_x\\ (-x\partial_x)^3=-x\partial_x(-x\partial_x+x^2\partial^2_x)=-x\partial_x-x^2\partial^2_x-x^3\partial_x^3$$